# Can I pass an object's instance method to a method expecting a callback in Scala?

Tags: scala, callback, functional-programming

Let's say I have a method expecting another method as a parameter. Is it possible to send an object's instance methods for that parameter? How would I handle methods that have no parameters?

I'll write some pseudocode:

```
void myMethod1(callback<void,int> otherFunc); // imagine a function returning void, and taking a int parameter

void myMethod2(callback<int,void> otherFunc); // function returning void, not taking params
```

if for example I have an ArrayList, like this:

```
val a = new ArrayList()
```

how could I send it's `add` method as parameter for `myMethod1`, and it's `size` method as parameter for `myMethod2`?

Comment: It's important to know and keep in mind that in Scala methods and functions are very different things. Methods are not first-class entities, but functions are. Thus (reflection aside), no method takes another method as a parameter. Partial application can be used with either methods or functions and always yields a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `myMethod4` may be what you mean when you say: "Isn't it possible to reference a.size and invoke it whenever needed?".

```
def myMethod1(f: Int => Unit): Unit = f(1)

def myMethod2(f: () => Int): Unit = {
  val value = f // f is function, taking no arguments, and returning an int.
                // we invoke it here.
  ()
}

def myMethod3(f: => Int): Unit = {
  val value = f // f is call by name parameter.
  ()
}

def myMethod4[A](f: A => Int, a: A): Unit = {
  val value = f(a)
  ()
}

import java.util.ArrayList

val a = new ArrayList[Int](1)
myMethod1((i: Int) => a.add(i))
myMethod1(a.add(_))     // shorthand for the above
myMethod2(() => a.size) // a.size is not evaluated, it is enclosed in an anonymous function definition.
myMethod3(a.size)       // a.size is not evaluated here, it is passed as a by-name parameter.
myMethod4((al: ArrayList[Int]) => al.size, a)
myMethod4((_: ArrayList[Int]).size, a)
myMethod4[ArrayList[Int]](_.size, a)
```

Comment: can you please explain how the empty parantheses work in method2/3/4 ?

Comment: A block `{a; b; c}` must contain a sequence of expressions and declarations (var, val, class, function, trait, object). It must finish with an expression. For clarity, I assigned the result of `f` to a val `value`, so I needed to follow this with an expression that conforms the the expected type of the block, which in this case is the declared type of the function: `Unit`. `()` is the one and only instance of the type `Unit`. An empty `return` would also work. As would an expression of any other type, as any value can be converted to type `Unit`.

Answer (score 5):

The type of a function in Scala is denoted

```
(Types,To,Pass) => ReturnType
```

(you can leave off the parens if there is only a single type to pass), and the way to convert a method into a function to pass to another method is

myObject.myMethod _

So, putting these together--and paying attention to the types of the Java classes:

```
scala> def addMySize(adder: Int => Boolean, sizer: () => Int) = adder(sizer())
addMySize: ((Int) => Boolean,() => Int)Boolean

scala> val a = new java.util.ArrayList[Int]()
a: java.util.ArrayList[Int] = []

scala> addMySize(a.add _, a.size _)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> addMySize(a.add _, a.size _)
res1: Boolean = true

scala> println(a)
[0, 1]
```

(Note that ArrayList has an add that takes an object and returns a boolean--not one that returns void.)

Answer (score 4):

```
def myMethod(callback : Int => Unit, size : => Int) = ...

myMethod(a.add _, a.size)
```

`Void` is represented through the type `Unit`.

Edit: Through the above use of `=> Int`, `size` is passed by name which means it's always re-evaluated when needed.

Comment: Isn't it possible to reference `a.size` and invoke it whenever needed?

Comment: Do you mean passing size:Int by name?

def myMethod(callback: Int => Unit, size: => Int)